# How to json encode multiple rows of data

Tags: php, json

i am working in yii. i am having table which is storing information and its related date.In following function i am searching information by providing date as input. i have function in controller as-

```
     public function actionGetHistoryContent()
      {
        $content1=new Dnycontenttitle();
        $content1->date="2013-01-01";
        $getcontentId=Dnycontenttitle::model()-   >indAllByAttributes(array("date"=>$content1->date));

        foreach ($getcontentId as $Id)
        {

         //echo $Id->contentTitleId;
         $getcontent=Dnycontent::model()->findAllByAttributes(array("contentTitleId"=>$Id->contentTitleId));
         foreach($getcontent as $content)
         {  
            echo "</br>".$content->content;
         }

      }  
     echo "{'Historys':    [".CJSON::encode(array("contentId"=>$Id>contentTitleId,"Intro"=>$content->content))."] }";
}
```

So above function is retreiving all rows of information which is having date as "2013-01-01". I want to send all these data in json format to client side. But above json is sending only one row of data which is lastly get retrieved by function.
e.g. suppose above function retrieves 2 rows of data from table as=

contentId=1    intro="Today is sunday"    Date=2013-01-01
     contentId=23   intro="World's smile day"  Date=2013-01-01

But when i am sending it through json,,it is sending only information of lastly retrieved contentId=23. 
So how to send multiple rows of data in json format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to do it inside the foreach(). otherwise you will get the last element..
Try this.

```
public function actionGetHistoryContent()
  {
    $content1=new Dnycontenttitle();
    $content1->date="2013-01-01";
    $getcontentId=Dnycontenttitle::model()-   >indAllByAttributes(array("date"=>$content1->date));
    foreach ($getcontentId as $Id)
     {
     $getcontent=Dnycontent::model()->findAllByAttributes(array("contentTitleId"=>$Id->contentTitleId));
     foreach($getcontent as $content)
     {  
        echo "</br>".$content->content;
        echo "{'Historys':    [".CJSON::encode(array("contentId"=>$Id>contentTitleId,"Intro"=>$content->content))."] }";
     }
  }
```

}

Comment: Thanx sir for your reply. But It is sending multiple json's to client side. Is it not possible to send all data in single json? Can you please help me.

Comment: For that you have to store the whole json in another array and pass that after the assiginig...